# How to disable default model binding for a particular class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to disable model binding for a particular class , to be more specific i don't want certain data property of a class to be set by the default model binding .

eg . i have height and width property of a class , which i want to be explicitly set by the user

like model.height = xxx ;

the value should not be set by default model binders even when i pass the model to the action method.

is there a way to do so ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Exlude](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.bindattribute.exclude.aspx), [Include](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.bindattribute.include.aspx) properties of [BindAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.bindattribute.aspx).

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude="Height")]MyModel model)
```

IMHO it's better to use Include than Exclude because in this way you are explicit at what properties should be automatically bound. Using Exclude might be a security risk and could be exploited by a hacker to set properties that are not intended to be set by the binder.

Comment: that is done on the users side , i dont have access to the controller ,iam just creating the model

Answer (score 1):

You could do it as darin suggests, or you can actually do it in the model class itself

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

[Bind(Exclude = "Height, Width")]
public class MyModelClass {
    ....
}
```

That way no matter where it's used those properties will never get bound. It would be more secure to be explicit, and provide an (Include =) list though, that way new properties don't get bound by default, and you are forced to include them, considering the security implications as you do so.